# condition for session in quiz sample

Tags: php

Here is the sample of process.php of a quiz.everything is ok but if user answer correct to a question and again back to question and again answer correct. Score add more and this is my problem with session ?

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
//get values
$number = $_POST['number'];
$selected_choice = $_POST['choice'];
$next = $number + 1 ;
//get NOQ
$query_NOQ = "select * from questions";
$result_NOQ = $connection->query($query_NOQ) or die($connection->error.__LINE__);
$NOQ = $result_NOQ ->num_rows;

$query_co = "select * from choices where question_number = $number AND is_correct = 1";
$result_co = $connection->query($query_co) or die($connection->error.__LINE__);
$correct_row = $result_co->fetch_assoc();
$correct_answer = $correct_row['id'];

if($selected_choice == $correct_answer){
    $_SESSION['score']++;
}
if($number == $NOQ){
    header("Location:final.php");
}  else {
    header("Location:questions.php?n=".$next);
}
```

Comment: No, that is not a session problem per se, but one with your logic. You are always adding to your counter, if the database query returned that the given answer was correct for the given question. You have implemented no logic at all so far that would check which questions have already been answered, or if this is a “changed” answer, or anything like that.

Comment: Add a flag for what questions have been answered to the session. Then check that before increment.

Comment: @nerdlyist would you tell me the code?

Comment: @sina you have two answers do either work? You seem to be having a track record of not accepting things that help you...

Answer (score 0):

You would do something like this:

```
//Check if there is something for that question
if(!isset($SESSION['answered_' .$number])){
    if($selected_choice == $correct_answer){
        $_SESSION['score']++;
    }
    //Set something so if they come back nothing happens to score
    $SESSION['answered_' .$number] = TRUE;
} else {
    //Could put some logic here that they already answered this one?
}


if($number == $NOQ){
    header("Location:final.php");
}  else {
    header("Location:questions.php?n=".$next);
}
```

Comment: What didn't work? It is to create a new session key for that question flagging it as answered already. You can then check to see if that key exists to know if you should increment the score. It could actually be around everything so you do not hit the db and all that as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the functionality to check whether user answered same question or not?

```
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $number = $_POST['number'];
    $selected_choice = $_POST['choice'];
    $next = $number + 1 ;
    //get NOQ
    $query_NOQ = "select * from questions";
    $result_NOQ = $connection->query($query_NOQ) or die($connection->error.__LINE__);
    $NOQ = $result_NOQ ->num_rows;

    /*check here that user already answer this question from database (add userid in the DB or join with userid for identical purpose 
    of related user*/

    $check = sonefunc();

    if($check==true){
        $query_co = "select * from choices where question_number = $number AND is_correct = 1";
        $result_co = $connection->query($query_co) or die($connection->error.__LINE__);
        $correct_row = $result_co->fetch_assoc();
        $correct_answer = $correct_row['id'];

        if($selected_choice == $correct_answer){
            $_SESSION['score']++;
        }
        if($number == $NOQ){
            header("Location:final.php");
        }  else {
            header("Location:questions.php?n=".$next);
        }
    }else{
        echo "Already answered this question";
    }
 }
```